# Can Jackson annotations be used along side JAXB?

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, jackson, jaxb

I have an endpoint and a RestController in my application.
The Payload is as follows :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ServiceInfoRequest", namespace = "myapp")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ServiceInfoRequestBase implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String username;

    private String password;
}
```

Here I want to use a common DTO for both the endpoint and the Rest Controller. Does using the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` (or any other jackson annotation) along with JAXB annotation like `@XmlElement/@XmlRootElement` cause any sort of problem?

Comment: No. But why don't you simply try

Comment: I had to send it as a hotfix so couldn't test.

Comment: You are doing a hotfix and cannot test it? That's very dangerous

Comment: By 'endpoint' do you mean SOAP webservice?

Comment: @Smile Yes sir.